# var_dump($_POST); is empty but not var_dump($_POST); die;

Tags: php, post

i have found some similar topics on this issue, but nothing for my case:

i send some post data via form, but the $_POST array is always empty (not null). but when i add a "die;" or "exit;" after var_dump($_POST); i can see all data sent.

maybe its relevant to know, that this is inside a (shopware) plugin which is called on "onPreDispatch".

thanks for any help

Comment: Are you calling the page via POST or GET?
Try using $_REQUEST.

Comment: i do not redirect, but i manipulate the request parameter which call another controller and action after the plugin routine is done. shopware is built on zend, so here is how i call the other controller after my routine was processed:  $request->setParam('sTarget', 'checkout');
$request->setControllerName('account');
$request->setActionName('savePayment');
$request->setActionName('savePayment')->setDispatched(false);        i noticed, that if i take out this code, i get my post data, but then i have no "connection" to the next action which initially has to be called.

Comment: is there another way how to call a specific action of another controller in zend?

Answer (score 1):

Your (shopware) plugin probably uses output buffering. Which means it will gather all the ecoes and prints until you call ob_flush() which prints all the buffer.

die() function, apart from everything else, also flushes the buffer when called.
So, if you do ob_flush() after your echo you should get the needed result.

Comment: That's a very, very long shot. I expect that the array "being empty (not null)" means that `print_r($_POST)` results in `Array ()`, in which case it's not output buffering.

Comment: thats right zneak, if i var_dump the post, i get "array(0) { }" its not about printing some data, i just need the content of the post, which i only can see in combination with die or exit.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the redirect, which resetted the post although it was after i read the parameters in the request.

i did not know, that shopware saves the desired data (paymentID) in the database. so i switched my plugin back to "onPostDispatch" (this way it will be called after all other actions, one of them saves the data in db). now i can just read the db and get the same data, which was initially in the post array.

i tried to be "the first" who reads the post, but could not work it out. now i am the last who reads it and it works fine.

thanks for all answers! the clue here was "redirect".