# Form method- GET working but POST not working

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, methods, get

I just ran in the form action `var_dump($_GET)`, it has given following results when I submitted the form and it is giving form values to the URL.

```
array (size=4)
'randomkey' => string 'asdf' (length=4)
'agreementid' => string 'adfas' (length=5)
'attachment' => string '' (length=0)
'upload' => string 'Add' (length=3)
```

But, When I ran the `var_dump($_POST)` with same form values it has given following results-

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

I have checked several thread of StackOverFlow.com, like- 
1. [PHP $_POST not working but $_GET works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386124/) 
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573071/ 
I have checked `RadCompression` `RadUploadModule` both are turned off. I have tried by removing `.php` from form action value, because I have removed `.php` extension using `.htaccess`

HTML @ below-

```
<form action=\"upload\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">
        <input type='text' value='' name='randomkey' />
        <input type='text' value='' name='agreementid' />
        <input type='file' name='attachment' />
        <input type='submit' name='upload' value='Add' />
    </form>
```

What Can I Do Right Now?

Comment: add the html code for your form

Comment: added html, please check @emeraldjava

Comment: what firebug shows to this request?

Comment: Firebug results following for `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, `array (size=3)
  'randomkey' => string 'afdsdf' (length=6)
  'agreementid' => string 'adsfasdf' (length=8)
  'upload' => string 'Add' (length=3)`

Comment: So the data is there, but $_POST is still empty? Are you sure, you are uploading the correct file?

Comment: I am uploading exact file type, i used in code. `$type == 'image/jpeg' ||
            $type == 'image/png' ||
            $type == 'image/gif'`

Comment: can you give web address?? the problem doesnt seems to be here.

Comment: are you sure your server has no restrictions on post?

Answer (score 0):

As viewing the `html` code you are using `POST` method, so you will get the result using `$_POST` not using `$_GET`.

Alternatively you can also use `$_REQUEST` for viewing the request coming.

Comment: His problem is that `$_POST` isn't returning anything.

Comment: @EM-Creations The same code is working fine in my end with `$_POST`. And I also said him to use alternate way.

Comment: I solved the problem and successfully inserted data to the table and moved multiple files to the directory. I will post the answer here.. Thanks all of you for giving me some ideas!

Answer (score 0):

use `die()` or `exit()` after `var_dump()` function ... i believe it will work ...