# Domain does not allow script to receive POST parameters

Tags: php, rest, post

I'm working with a domain where surprisingly $_POST array is always empty.

I've changed the script to another location (domain) and it does receive the parameters and I can print them.

What could be affecting it? httpaccess? any php.ini setting?

```
<?php
echo "POST<br>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br>--------------</br>";
```

Comment: $_REQUEST is working?

Comment: try a `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`

Comment: just POST stuff is uppressed? please add a minimal working example and its output… it also should show if GET and REQUEST are fine.

Comment: Yep, REQUEST works, empty too. If I try with get I can print the $_GET array

Comment: maybe its cross domain, ajax POST ?

Comment: take a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/how-to-filter-post-requests-before-they-reach-php-on-apache

Comment: well, I'm using httprequester to check it (after I noticed the problem). The same request works for the same script in domain A, but when I change the url to domain B, the array is empty

Comment: check post_max_size must less than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: @AhmedGinani tried changing upload_max_filesize from 2 to 10, post_max_size is 8. Still nothing.

Comment: Get method working fine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386124/php-post-not-working-but-get-works-fine

Comment: Maybe you'll also find answers on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission

Comment: yes, the GET method works

Comment: @user1915746 thanks a lot, I'll post the solution right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @icesar, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission)

"Here's another possible cause -- my form was submitting to domain.com without the WWW. and I had set up an automatic redirect to add the "WWW." The $_POST array was getting emptied in the process. So to fix it all I had to do was submit to www.domain.com"